# iOS7 v iOS8 presentViewController code running in different order

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, swift, ios8

I have an iOS app that was built on iOS7, and trying to get it working for iOS8, but it seems a simple function call is running differently between the two OS's.

Here is the code and the println outputs per OS (below)

```
  ...
  if (self.getReachabilityStatus() == 0) {
    self.showNoConnectionView()
  } else {
    self.checkForWalkthrough()
    println("foo")
  }

  println("baz")

  return true
}

//Check if user has run through walkthrough.
func checkForWalkthrough() {         
  if (!self.walkthroughCompleted()) {
    self.navigationController.presentViewController(self.walkthroughViewController, animated: false, completion: { println("bar") })
   }
}
```

iOS7 Outputs::

```
bar
foo
baz
```

iOS8 Outputs::

```
foo
baz
bar
```

Why would this be?

Comment: Does this happen consistently?

Comment: Yes, I've run multiple times on real devices each running one of the OS's. The output is always the same.